# Minimum Sdk Version Windows 10 (UWP)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I'm using VS2015 with SDK 10240 .

I've build my application already (with **C#**) ... But I can't run it on my windows 10 mobile cause it's build 10130.

How can I change **min SDK** of my application ?

Do I've to download and install the old SDK ?

Can I debug it on my Windows 10 mobile?

Comment: Is this a C# application? There's a manual workaround but if you are calling any APIs that were introduced between 10130 and 10240, the app will break. If it's C# let me know and I'll answer with the workaround.

Comment: @DanielJacobson Yes, I'm using C# ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To manually work around this (don't forget, the app may break on phone), you can do the following:

1. Right click on your project in the solution explorer
2. Click "Unload Project"
3. Right click again and edit [yourapp].csproj
4. Find TargetPlatformMinVersion and change it (in this case, to 10.0.10130.0 or lower)
5. Save the file and reload the project (right click on the project in solution explorer, "Reload project")

Your mileage may vary with this as 10130 is a prerelease build of Windows.Mobile. If you need to test/debug on Windows.Mobile, I recommend using the Windows 10 10.0.10240.0 emulators, but I recognize there are some advantages to trying on a real phone.